# Deleted Rails migration causing Heroku "release failed" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

We use Heroku review apps for QAing our PRs on Github. At some point a couple months ago we did some housekeeping and deleted a lot of old migration files and I think that is causing issues with the deploy on Heroku.

Here is my app.json file -

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "rake db:migrate db:seed db:fixtures:repopulate"
  },
  "env": {
    "WEB_CONCURRENCY": "1",
    "HEROKU_APP_NAME": {
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "formation": {
  },
  "addons": [
    "heroku-redis",
    {
      "plan": "heroku-postgresql",
      "options": {
        "version": "9.6"
      }
    }
  ],
  "buildpacks": [

  ]
}
```

Here is the results of running `heroku releases:output` -

```
Migrating to PopulateOldPasswordTable (20180305160642)
   (1.3ms)  BEGIN
== 20180305160642 PopulateOldPasswordTable: migrating =========================
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
   (1.2ms)  ROLLBACK
   (1.4ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(5078732648953702200)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIM...
                               ^
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:589:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `exec_no_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:587:in `execute_and_clear'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:103:in `exec_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:373:in `select'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:41:in `select_all'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:95:in `select_all'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:702:in `exec_queries'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:583:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:260:in `records'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:200:in `block in in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:198:in `loop'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:198:in `in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:120:in `find_in_batches'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:58:in `find_each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `find_each'
/app/db/migrate/20180305160642_populate_old_password_table.rb:3:in `change'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you deleted a migration that hadn't been run in all environments. You really don't want to do that.

The simplest way to recover, if the database doesn't contain anything of value, would be to destroy it and recreate it from scratch -- that'll use your `schema.rb` file, which should better match your other working environments.

If that isn't an option, consider bringing the old migration(s) back [via your git history], at least until you've finished running them everywhere.

Comment: We cleaned up and removed some of our old migrations so it looks like its failing on the first migration it gets to where it expects a table thats not there, in this case `users`.

I'm trying to have it load from schema but its still seems like its running the migrations first. Here is what I have in my app.json - `"postdeploy": "rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load"`